# How to add validation for data retrieved

Tags: sql, oracle

I currently have the below query and the results are in the following format:

```
with instances as 
(
    select
        m.member_target_name target_name,
        m.aggregate_target_name system_name,
        t.host_name hostname,
        init.value expected_num_instances
    from 
        DB_target_members m
    join 
        DB_target t on m.member_target_name = t.target_name
    join 
        DB_db_init_params_all init on m.member_target_name = init.target_name 
                                   and init.name = 'cluster_database_instances'
    where 
        upper(m.aggregate_target_name) = upper(:s)
        and m.member_target_type = 'oracle_database'
),
properties as 
(
    select *
    from 
        (select 
             i.target_name, tp.property_name, tp.property_value, 
             i.expected_num_instances
         from 
             instances i
         join 
             DB_target_properties tp on tp.target_name = i.target_name
         where 
             tp.property_name in ('DBName', 'InstanceName', 'DataGuardStatus',
                                  'orcl_gtp_lifecycle_status', 'SID', 'RACInstNum')
        )
    pivot 
        (max(property_value)
             for property_name in ('DBName' db_unique_name,
                                   'orcl_gtp_lifecycle_status' environment,
                                   'InstanceName' instance_name,
                                   'RACInstNum' instance_number,
                                   'DataGuardStatus' role,
                                   'SID' sid)
         )
    order by 
        db_unique_name, instance_number
)
select
    p.*,
    i.system_name,
    i.hostname,
    (row_number() over (partition by p.db_unique_name order by p.instance_number) - 1) instance_index
from 
    instances i
join 
    properties p on i.target_name = p.target_name
```

RESULTS:

```
target_name ;expected_num_instances; db_unique_name;environment ;instance_name; instance_number; role;sid; system_name; hostname;      instance_index       
PROD_DB_orahost1_PROD_DB1   2   PROD_DB_orahost1    Production  PROD_DB1    1   Primary PROD_DB1    PROD_DB_orahost2_sys    orahost1.svr.us.jpmchase.net    0
PROD_DB_orahost1_PROD_DB2   2   PROD_DB_orahost1    Production  PROD_DB2    2   Primary PROD_DB2    PROD_DB_orahost2_sys    orahost11.svr.us.jpmchase.net   1
PROD_DB_orahost2_PROD_DB1   2   PROD_DB_orahost2    Production  PROD_DB1    1   Standby PROD_DB1    PROD_DB_orahost2_sys    orahost2.svr.us.jpmchase.net    0
PROD_DB_orahost2_PROD_DB2   2   PROD_DB_orahost2    Production  PROD_DB2    2   Standby PROD_DB2    PROD_DB_orahost2_sys    orahost22.svr.us.jpmchase.net   1
```

I am currently validating the results in python code ,but need to integrate the validation in the SQL itself which i am having trouble with using 'case' condition.
The validations are:

1. check if the 'environment' is same for all rows,if not then the target 's' is FAIL.
2. check if the 'system_name' is same for all rows,if not then the target 's' is FAIL.
   The overall result expected is like:

   target_name  result   error
   xyz           FAIL    environment/system_name not unique

Comment: What version is your Oracle Database?

Comment: 11.2.0.4 or 12c

Answer (score 1):

I took only the query part without the `WITH` clause and modify like below,

```
select p.*
      ,i.system_name
      ,i.hostname
      ,case 
         when (count(distinct p.environment) over() + 
               count(distinct i.system_name) over()) = 2 -- if all same we get sum as 2
         then 'PASS' 
         else 'FAIL' 
       end as result
      ,(row_number() over (partition by p.db_unique_name order by p.instance_number) - 1) instance_index
  from instances i
  join properties p
    on i.target_name = p.target_name;
```

I would suggest to create one level sub query if you need also the `error` message to be part of the query result set

Comment: Is it possible to get the overall 'result' only.Currently i have made few minor changes to the query you suggested and getting the below output:
environment   system_name   hostname        result
Production prod_host1_sys host1a.oracle PASS
Production prod_host1_sys host1b.oracle PASS
Production prod_host1_sys host2a.oracle PASS
Production prod_host1_sys host2b.oracle PASS

Comment: @vivek, Do you mean only one row for all as `result` either `PASS` or `FAIL` ?

Comment: then wouldn't be good to edit the answer but what you can do with current query is , in case statement instead of `PASS` or `FAIL` pass as  `1` and `0` respectively and then with one level sub query like `select case min(result) = 0 then 'FAIL' else 'PASS' end as result from ( the existing query whatever you have )`

Comment: Thanks Sujit..just one more question...how can i display only if the result is FAIL

Comment: I would add extra condition to where clause as `where min(result) = 0` and it will return you one row with `FAIL` then and in case of result is `PASS` you won't get any result.

Answer (score 1):

Using `COUNT (DISTINCT value)` and checking that it is greater than 1 will help you find if you have more than 1 distinct value:

```
WITH
    test_data (target_name,
               expected_num_instances,
               db_unique_name,
               environment,
               instance_name,
               instance_number,
               role,
               sid,
               system_name,
               hostname,
               instance_index)
    AS
        (SELECT 'PROD_DB_orahost1_PROD_DB1',
                2,
                'PROD_DB_orahost1',
                'Production',
                'PROD_DB1',
                1,
                'Primary',
                'PROD_DB1',
                'PROD_DB_orahost2_sys',
                'orahost1.svr.us.jpmchase.net',
                0
           FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'PROD_DB_orahost1_PROD_DB2',
                2,
                'PROD_DB_orahost1',
                'Production',
                'PROD_DB2',
                2,
                'Primary',
                'PROD_DB2',
                'PROD_DB_orahost2_sys',
                'orahost11.svr.us.jpmchase.net',
                1
           FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'PROD_DB_orahost2_PROD_DB1',
                2,
                'PROD_DB_orahost2',
                'Production',
                'PROD_DB1',
                1,
                'Standby',
                'PROD_DB1',
                'PROD_DB_orahost2_sys',
                'orahost2.svr.us.jpmchase.net',
                0
           FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'PROD_DB_orahost2_PROD_DB2',
                2,
                'PROD_DB_orahost2',
                'Production',
                'PROD_DB2',
                2,
                'Standby',
                'PROD_DB2',
                'PROD_DB_orahost2_sys',
                'orahost22.svr.us.jpmchase.net',
                1
           FROM DUAL)
SELECT o.*, CASE WHEN error_message IS NULL THEN 'PASS' ELSE 'FAIL' END
  FROM (SELECT td.*,
               CASE
                   WHEN (SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT environment) FROM test_data) > 1
                   THEN
                       'Environment is not the same for all rows'
                   WHEN (SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT system_name) FROM test_data) > 1
                   THEN
                       'System name is not the same for all rows'
                   ELSE
                       NULL
               END    AS error_message
          FROM test_data td) o
```

Comment: `COUNT(DISTINCT value)` has been standard for ages. I am sure that Oracle has supported this for at least twenty-eight years (i.e. since Oracle 7), probably even longer.

Comment: @Thorsten - You are correct, I had mistaken `COUNT(DISTINCT value)` for `LISTAGG(DISTINCT value)` (which is new in 19c).  Post has been updated. Thank you!